# Is there any os virtualization without having to install a full OS (needed multiple similar vms)?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I wanted to have a separate virtualized OS environment (preferably Windows but Linux is also welcome) but running on a very small RAM to run a bot application.
I have tried Hyper-V (with disk differencing) and VMware (with linked/instant clones) and Virtualbox and qemu but so far they need full OS installation and it can take up so much space.

Basically I just needed multiple similar environment (close to 100) without having a big HDD space and I run all the apps from a local network folder. 
(Similar to multiple vms running under one vhd but I dont want to take up so many HDD spaces)

I have tried using one customised Lubuntu livecd and WINPE live cd (Gandalf's WINPE 7) booting on multiple Hyper-V vms. They boot just fine but Gandalf's WINPE is not a full windows and require a high RAM usage while on Linux side I cant run my windows script + app well under WINE though Linux memory management is much better and I still can use a much smaller distro like Damn Small Linux if need be.

I checked Microsoft's App-V but it just virtualised the app not setting up a new standalone environment. I need a new environment with their own mouse pointer but needing very small RAM preferably just for running the bot and the app.

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at FreeBSD jails.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Is there any video showing how the setup look like? I am totally in the dark about FreeBSD.

Comment: I don't know about videos, but there is a Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD_jail

Comment: oh are they similar to Docker containers and Linux LXC/LXD? I still need to access the gui though

Comment: Yes, but Docker is actually way more recent than Jails

Comment: The thing about containers that I am still not sure about is whether they can run 2 processes in 1 container. I was thinking that containers were like multiple desktop users sharing same resources but it turns out to be far different. I have researched LXC and it seems to be close enough for my intended usage. I cant find any video that shows FreeBSD jails having desktop GUI access.

Comment: Yes, they can run more than one process.

Comment: Oh if my docker  research turn out to suit for my needs would that mean everything I do in docker can also be applied to LXC/LXD/FreeBSD jails? since Docker is based on LXC

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Also see Debian QEMU/Chroot's. You can find some information about them at [Debian Chroot](https://cryptopp.com/wiki/Debian_Chroot).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried FreeBSD Jail, LXC, LXD, but unable to make it the way I want it to be (having one PC with multiple users but on a minimal footprint).

However, I am excited that I kind of find the solution and would like to share it.

> **For Windows host machine + Linux guest**
>
> 1. Enable Hyper-V in Windows (if supported) or download VirtualBox
> 2. Install Docker for Windows
> 3. Install RealVNC (or any other VNC client)
> 4. Download (pull) or create any linux docker image with desktop
>      environment + VNC (optional: wine, winetricks, playonlinux for running windows apps + cimb-utils [it is for smb sharing network folder])
> 5. In powershell deploy multiple container using same image + assign each
>      different vnc port, for example :
>
>    For VNC + Samba network sharing + vncpassword
>
>    - *docker run -it --user 0 -d -p **5900**:5900 -e VNC_PW=passwd --privileged --cap-add SYS_ADMIN --cap-add DAC_READ_SEARCH --security-opt seccomp=unconfined ubuntu*
>
>    For only VNC without vncpassword (depends on container)
>
>    - *docker run -d -p **5900**:5900 abrahamb/lubuntu-vnc*
>    - *docker run -d -p **5901**:5900 abrahamb/lubuntu-vnc*
>    - *docker run -d -p **5902**:5900 abrahamb/lubuntu-vnc*
>    - etc
> 6. Open RealVNC and setup a connection to these addresses; for example :
>
>    - *localhost:**5900***
>    - *localhost:**5901***
>    - *localhost:**5902***
>    - etc
> 7. Each ports will lead to separate containerised desktops

That way, you will have one base image for deploying multiple containers (like having one computer multiple users running at the same time) only requiring minimal RAM usage and Disk Size.
Another way is to boot a base live iso in multiple Hyper-V VMs. However, they are RAM intensive and can only deploy several separate environment.

**Further info+findings:**

Docker is actually kinda similar to LXC, LXD, and FreeBSD Jails since they are all containerised image. I believe if I try hard enough I can make similar setup in LXD. FreeBSD Jails might be a good alternative too.

However, I didnt try further since I couldnt find enough information regarding jails setup. I couldnt find any Youtube video that explains how to setup, only some articles/blog but still too frustrating since I dont have enough time to research further.

LXD/LXC can be configured to virtualize a desktop but not quite what I am looking for since that would mean I have to dual-boot/have Ubuntu vm.

Docker just recently implement Windows container but the base image is GUI-less. In the Linux side however, there are quite a few available images that have been configured with bare minimal desktop environment.

Also, using Docker, I dont need to have VM that is running Ubuntu/FreeBSD to setup lxd/lxc/jails or dual-booting Linux/FreeBSD. Another plus, Docker is *cross-platform* (can be used in Windows/Linux/MacOs).

tldr; Docker is awesome.